# Columns and rows in flutter

Tags: flutter, frontend, mobile-application

I am writing my first flutter project as a graduation project for college and I noticed that I use too many columns and rows in my classes, I want to know if that is a good thing or not and if there is better ways?

Answer (score 3):

If you are an Android developer, you can compare Flutter's Row and Column with Android's LinearLayout horizontal and LinearLayout vertical .

In Android, all the other layouts and components are a combination of the above two linear layouts.

Similarly, In Flutter, all the major widgets like ListTile and GridView are internally nothing but a combination of Rows and Columns. So, it's just a matter of choice to whether pick a pre-built widget and use it in your app, or use Rows and Columns and design a custom widget from scratch. Only advantage you have in the later part is that you can have more flexibility.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a bad thing except if you see performance problems. But if you need scroll, it's better to use something like ListView or GridView which are more performant.